# How to get name of interface on which is send packet to specific ip address in c

Tags: c, interface, ip

I wanna know my ip address which i'm using to send some data to mdns address. I know how to find it when i know interface's name, but it's not the same on diffrent machine. Is any way to find it in c?

Answer (score 0):

If you've done a `connect(2)`, the local address details for that socket are available via the `getsockname(2)` call. Tricky parts are supporting both IPv4 and IPv6, passing a buffer (and `socklen_t` length) of sufficient size for `getsockname` to fill in, then appropriate `inet_ntop` calls for the `AF_*` family in question if you want to print the IP address as a string.